# Facebook api - invalid token

Tags: facebook, api

tried to send post to facebook api to scrape my page at load.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jd0y.png

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: please post your code here. a photo is never a good idea. we can't retype all your code to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you use [FB.api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api/):

```
FB.api('/', 'post', {
    id: 'url-to-scrape',
    scrape: true
}, function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Not sure where you got that code example from, but you should always take a look at the Facebook docs.

Answer (score 0):

I you are getting invalid token means your token is not correct let me tell you how to generate token it is simply by combining your app id and app secret gotten on Facebook developers app dashboard after you have signed up [check here and read url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTTkJ.png) and to check errors faster on your code api, download post man here  **www.getpostman.com,** put in your api call code in the url bar and hit send it will tell you your error. Then to get token for facebook fancount,pageid,likescount, you can do a search for more info on **graph.facebook.com** on google. contact me if there is problem.

```
       $appid = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
       $appsecret = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";
    //get it from your dashboard 
       $token = $appid .|. $appsecret key
```